# Как выводить перед html формой несоответствие условия

Tags: php, html

Как выводить перед html формой например "Не правильный логин!"? 
То есть если условие неверно, то на той же станице перед формой выводится в каком поле именно ошибка??
Я делаю так, но это не то что надо:

```
 if ((strlen($username) >= 3) and (strlen($username) <= 40))
       {
       $username = stripslashes($username);
       $username = html_entity_decode($username);
       $username = strip_tags($username);
       $username = htmlspecialchars($username);}    
        else {echo "Не правильный логин!";}
```

И есть проблема, у меня форма и обработчик в 2х разных файлах, но предназначено чтобы только незарегистрированные пользователи видели форму регистрации, а зарегис. перенаправлялись на главную.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) || (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password']))) 
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/');
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST['GO'])) //если была нажата кнопка регистрации, проверим данные на корректность и, если данные введены и введены правильно, добавим запись с новым пользователем в БД
   { ТУТ проверки на правильность вводов}
else
 {
    include("reg.php"); //подключаем шаблон в случае если кнопка регистрации нажата не была, то есть, пользователь только перешёл на страницу регистрации
 }
```

Файл reg.php и есть html форма регистрации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если я верно понял то - я делаю так:

$html = '<form acton=""> и т.д. ';

в ходе

```
if(empty($_POST['login'] or $_POST['...']))
{
  $error = 1;
}

if(empty($error))
{
  true;
}
else
{
  false;
  echo $html;
}
```

Все примитивно но равно к сути!

**UPD//** К тоу же дополню что нужно важные поля проверять на регулярные выраженя и прочие вещи...

Короче говоря проще написать ckass котороый будет обрабатывать входящие данные!

Comment: А какой должен быть class?
Можете маленький примерчик показать, если не трудно..